# Python 3.10 cannot import pyzbar

Tags: python, dll, barcode, zbar, filenotfounderror

i am using pyzbar 0.1.9 for a barcode reader but when i try to import pyzbar.pyzbar i get this error:

*FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\galax\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\libzbar-64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.*

i am using python version 3.10.6, is there any way to solve this problem?

this is how im trying to import pyzbar:

```
    from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode # <-- error in this line
```

Is there something I'm missing? or is the package corrupted?

i tried uninstalling and installing but it didnt work tho...

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the pyzbar [README](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar):

> If you see an ugly ImportError when importing pyzbar on Windows you will most likely need the [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784). Install vcredist_x64.exe if using 64-bit Python, vcredist_x86.exe if using 32-bit Python.

So, you need to:

- Uninstall pyzbar
- install those [Visual C++ redistributables](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784)  to make pyzbar work on Windows. (vcredist_x64.exe for 64-bit Python)
- Reinstall pyzbar

---

For more info, see also the discussion on [pyzbar Issue 93](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/issues/93)